# CMake undefined symbol: pthread_create compiling dynamic library

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake, shared-libraries

My project was working fine before but I changed it to be compiled as a dynamic library in order to have it perform self-update, like so:

- Launcher -> Executable
- Server -> Library (Core project, multi-threaded with std::thread)
- Updater -> Library

Now, on Linux (Debian Bullseye), I get a runtime error `undefined symbol: pthread_create` when the launcher tries to dlopen the Server library. Windows equivalent works fine.

I've tried splitting my big CMakeLists in several subprojects, thinking it could be a CMake bug, but that was of course not the problem.

I've included below a simplified version of the parent CMakeLists and the subproject CMakeLists for the Server and the launcher.

Parent:

```
################################
# Project settings
################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(TARGET_NAME "Server")
set(SERVER_VERSION "1.0.0")

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")
project(${TARGET_NAME} VERSION ${SERVER_VERSION} DESCRIPTION "My Server")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

################################
# Sources
################################
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Resource.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/Resource.h
    COPYONLY)
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Resource.rc.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/Resource.rc
    @ONLY)
set_source_files_properties("../Server.ico" PROPERTIES LANGUAGE RC)

include_directories("includes")

################################
# Subprojects
################################
add_subdirectory("src/Server")
add_subdirectory("src/Launcher")
add_subdirectory("src/Updater")
```

Server lib Subproject:

```
################################
# Project settings
################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(TARGET_NAME "Server-Core")
if (LIB)
    set(EXE_NAME "ServerCore")
else ()
    set(EXE_NAME "Server")
endif ()

project(${TARGET_NAME} VERSION ${SERVER_VERSION} DESCRIPTION "My Server")

################################
# Sources
################################
configure_file(
    Server.hh.in
    Server.hh
    @ONLY)

include_directories(. "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/Server/")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "*.hh" "*.hpp" "*.cpp" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/*.hh")
if (LIB)
    add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${SRC})
elseif (WIN32)
    add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/Resource.rc)
else ()
    add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC})
endif ()

################################
# Libs
################################
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} Threads::Threads)

if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} wsock32 ws2_32)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} Crypt32)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libssl.lib)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libcrypto.lib)
elseif(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libssl.a)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libcrypto.a)
endif()

################################
# Compiler settings
################################

set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION ${SERVER_VERSION})
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME ${EXE_NAME})

if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC /std:c++latest)
    target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC /Zc:__cplusplus)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /MANIFEST:NO")
endif()
```

Launcher subproject:

```
################################
# Project settings
################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(LAUNCHER_TARGET "Launcher")
set(LAUNCHER_EXE_NAME "Server")
set(LAUNCHER_VERSION "1.0.0")

project(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} VERSION ${LAUNCHER_VERSION} DESCRIPTION "My Server")

################################
# Sources
################################
if (LIB)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "*.hh" "*.hpp" "*.cpp"
        "../Server/Utils/DynamicLibrary/DynamicLibraryWindows.cpp" "../Server/Utils/DynamicLibrary/DynamicLibraryLinux.cpp"
        "../Server/Utils/DynamicLibrary/IDynamicLibrary.cpp")

    if (WIN32)
        add_executable(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} ${SRC} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/Resource.rc)
    else ()
        add_executable(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} ${SRC})
    endif ()
endif ()

################################
# Libs
################################

if (UNIX)
    if (LIB)
        target_link_libraries(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
    endif ()
endif ()

################################
# Compiler settings
################################

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} Threads::Threads)

if (LIB)
    set_target_properties(${LAUNCHER_TARGET} PROPERTIES VERSION ${LAUNCHER_VERSION})

    set_property(TARGET ${LAUNCHER_TARGET} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
    set_property(TARGET ${LAUNCHER_TARGET} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    set_property(TARGET ${LAUNCHER_TARGET} PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME ${LAUNCHER_EXE_NAME})
endif ()
```

I'm using CMake 3.16.3 and gcc 9.3.0

What did I do wrong? I'm still not extremely comfortable with CMake

Comment: Building what target produces the error you mentioned?

Comment: Can you provide the print of the fail from your cmae command please.

Comment: It's hard to tell but you don't seem to be getting a build error but a runtime error.  You said that it happens when dlopen gets called.  Right? Otherwise you don't seem to be building this correctly as Launcher doesn't appear to be linked against threads to know about pthread_create.

Comment: The error happens when I build with variables UNIX and LIB. Sorry, it wasn't clear in my message, I don't get any error from CMake or the build process, only a runtime error saying `Error: Server.so: undefined symbol: pthread_create`
I tried linking launcher against threads, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: After looking with nm, it appears that no thread symbol is found in the launcher executable. But my Launcher cmake should have linked threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to fix the problem by adding

`target_link_libraries(${TARGET} pthread)`

after

`target_link_libraries(${TARGET} Threads::Threads)`

for the Launcher, when compiling for Linux.

And I need to include `<thread>` in the launcher and have a piece of code such as

```
std::thread t([](){});
t.join();
```

This is extremely weird